# Why is animated GEOJSON path invisible in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have been trying to animate a path over a leaflet map using the following example from Mike Bostock:

http://bl.ocks.org/zross/6a31f4ef9e778d94c204

After i make my own json and put it into code, i get nothing, or maybe I get something - a yellow circle on the left-top corner, as you can see here:

http://mdurazob.info/mapaleaf2.html

```
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([23.995244, -103.020029], 5);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors | Tiles Courtesy of MapQuest ',
  subdomains: ['otile1', 'otile2', 'otile3', 'otile4']
}).addTo(mymap);

var svg = d3.select(mymap.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");
var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

d3.json("rutahidalgo.geojson", function(collection) {
  var featuresdata = collection.features.filter(function(d) {
    return d.properties.id == "route1"
    });

  var transform = d3.geo.transform({
      point: projectPoint
  });

  var d3path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

  var toLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear").x(function(d) {
      return applyLatLngToLayer(d).x
    }).y(function(d) {
      return applyLatLngToLayer(d).y
  });

  var ptFeatures = g.selectAll("circle").data(featuresdata).enter().append("circle").attr("r", 3).attr("class", "waypoints");
  var linePath = g.selectAll(".lineConnect").data([featuresdata]).enter().append("path").attr("class", "lineConnect");
  var marker = g.append("circle").attr("r", 10).attr("id", "marker").attr("class", "travelMarker");
    mymap.on("viewreset", reset);

  function reset() {
      var bounds = d3path.bounds(collection),
        topLeft = bounds[0],
        bottomRight = bounds[1];

      text.attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + applyLatLngToLayer(d).x + "," + applyLatLngToLayer(d).y + ")";
      });

      begend.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + applyLatLngToLayer(d).x + "," + applyLatLngToLayer(d).y + ")";
      });

      ptFeatures.attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + applyLatLngToLayer(d).x + "," + applyLatLngToLayer(d).y + ")";
      });

      marker.attr("transform", function() {
          var y = featuresdata[0].geometry.coordinates[1]
          var x = featuresdata[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
          return "translate(" + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x)).x + "," + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x)).y + ")";
      });

      svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0] + 120).attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1] + 120).style("left", topLeft[0] - 50 + "px").style("top", topLeft[1] - 50 + "px");

      linePath.attr("d", toLine) g.attr("transform", "translate(" + (-topLeft[0] + 50) + "," + (-topLeft[1] + 50) + ")");
  }

  function transition() {
      linePath.transition().duration(7500).attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash).each("end", function() {
          d3.select(this).call(transition);
      });
  }

  function tweenDash() {
      return function(t) {
          var l = linePath.node().getTotalLength();
          interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
          var marker = d3.select("#marker");
          var p = linePath.node().getPointAtLength(t * l);
          marker.attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")");
          console.log(interpolate(t)) return interpolate(t);
      }
  }

  function projectPoint(x, y) {
      var point = mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
      this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
  }

});
```

**AND this is the geojson:**

```
{  
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "crs":{  
        "type":"name",
        "properties":{  
            "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features":[  
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":21.159216,
                "longitude":-100.934121,
                "time":1,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -100.934121,
                    21.159216
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":20.527743,
                "longitude":-100.807746,
                "time":2,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -100.807746,
                    20.527743
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":20.951976,
                "longitude":-101.427837,
                "time":3,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -101.427837,
                    20.951976
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":21.018937,
                "longitude":-101.257851,
                "time":4,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -101.257851,
                    21.018937
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":19.768333,
                "longitude":-101.189444,
                "time":5,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -101.189444,
                    19.768333
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":19.283333,
                "longitude":-99.35,
                "time":6,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -99.35,
                    19.283333
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":20.095711,
                "longitude":-99.838028,
                "time":7,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -99.838028,
                    20.095711
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":19.768333,
                "longitude":-101.189444,
                "time":8,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -101.189444,
                    19.768333
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":19.989644,
                "longitude":-102.288057,
                "time":9,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -102.288057,
                    19.989644
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":20.291022,
                "longitude":-102.544298,
                "time":10,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -102.544298,
                    20.291022
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":20.674278,
                "longitude":-103.010037,
                "time":11,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -103.010037,
                    20.674278
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":22.176245,
                "longitude":-102.340678,
                "time":12,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -102.340678,
                    22.176245
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":22.769783,
                "longitude":-102.582096,
                "time":13,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -102.582096,
                    22.769783
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":22.931168,
                "longitude":-101.092904,
                "time":14,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -101.092904,
                    22.931168
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":23.127954,
                "longitude":-101.114198,
                "time":15,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -101.114198,
                    23.127954
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":23.644761,
                "longitude":-100.643697,
                "time":16,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -100.643697,
                    23.644761
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{  
                "latitude":23.821589,
                "longitude":-100.724147,
                "time":17,
                "id":"route1",
                "name":"Along route"
            },
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -100.724147,
                    23.821589
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My first observation, would be that the function reset is never being entered. I put a break point there, and it never got hit. Also, could you reduce the code a bit and/or format it or put it in jsFiddle.

Comment: Hi, I tried to clean the code, and then edit the post. Do you mean this reset function? function reset() {
    var bounds = d3path.bounds(collection),
        topLeft = bounds[0],
        bottomRight = bounds[1];
    text.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + applyLatLngToLayer(d)
            .x + "," + applyLatLngToLayer(d)
            .y + ")";
    });

Comment: Yes, when I ran your example, the reset function was never entered.

Comment: the code was a mess but now it is more clean, the reset function is already in the code, as it is in the second webpage i mentioned, i find it strange that a yellow circle appears in the corner

Answer (score 2):

As for animating a path, you might be interested in using [Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim) plugin, instead of trying to achieve the result through D3.

You just have to create the intermediate `L.polyline`'s between each point in your GeoJSON data, possibly adding the point themselves (as `L.marker`'s), then call `snakeIn()` on the resulting Layer Group.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/36/

Note: the plugin is compatible with Leaflet 1.0, but not with Leaflet 0.7.